# PHP Getting the following error: "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' "

Tags: php

I'm trying to retrieve a single row with the following function:

```
function get_registrar($key){
    global $db;

    $query = 'SELECT * FROM registration WHERE key = :key';
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':key', $key);
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $statement->fetch();
    $statement->closeCursor();
    return $result;
}
```

And I keep getting "Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]:" error messages. Any idea why this might be? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

key is a reserved key word

so backtick it as

```
 `key`

$query = 'SELECT * FROM registration WHERE `key` = :keyval';
```

Here is the list of reserved keywords

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Thanks, I changed the $key to something else, but still getting the error.

Comment: Can I use "key" in my table?

Comment: no u cant use key in your table or in col names if u use u need to back tick.. for binding variables its ok

Comment: Perfect, I changed in the table and all is well. Still new to this stuff. Thank you